# How to use a drawable with a gradient in a ListView's pressed state?

Tags: android, android-listview, gradient

I'm currently using a drawable for all of my buttons, which gets a gradient over it when you press the button. I achieve this effect by using the various pressed-states and a `layer-list`.

Now I'm trying to create the same effect with a `ListView`. I'm able to show a different picture as the background for an object in the list when I click it, but whenever I try to add a picture with a separate gradient it shows up with the default Android color when clicking an object in the `ListView`. But, it does show my custom gradient on this default color.

I know this sounds a bit vague, so I took some screenshots to show the effect:

**Button with gradient overlay, works fine**

[image]

**ListView with a background per object, does not work when using that image plus a gradient overlay**

[image]

**The drawable I'm using as the background image for the `ListView`**

[image]

What could be the reason for the gradient working on the button, but not on the `ListView`? Like I said, using a completely different image for the pressed state works fine, but using the background image plus a gradient doesn't.

**Code used for the ListView pressed states**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Active tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_gradient" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- Inactive tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_listpage_77px" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <!-- Pressed tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_gradient" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_listpage_77px" />

</selector>
```

**list_gradient.xml**

```
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#880f0f10" android:centerColor="#8858585a" android:endColor="#88a9a9a9"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

---

After fiddling around for a few hours today, I still haven't been able to fix my problem. I know I'm missing something but I can't seem to figure out what. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: what is the listview's xml? are u setting the background to #00000000?

Comment: I did set the background to `#00000000`, but I did not set the `ListSelector` to do the same. After changing that, it worked! Thanks anyway though.

Comment: hehe am such a master :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going over everything again, and reading all similar questions here on SO again, I noticed that nowhere in my files I used 'android:listSelector`.

After setting the following in my `ListView`:

`android:listSelector="#00000000"`, my `ListView` behaved as I wanted to!

I figured that the `ListView` would work the same as all buttons, but I was wrong. Learn from my mistake, it might save you a whole lot of time.